# Failed First post review

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

A long time ago I failed [a review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15831601).

This question looks wrong for me because:

"Is there anything you can't do with a negation on a while statement?"
-> Until..While with a negation .. It look like a dumb question every time you say it out loud.

"Is it faster"
-> Have you tried? Any benchmark, data anything? Any question about optimisation without at least a try to estimate the fastest one is wrong ini my mind.

The 'until' instead of `until` buzz me. Like the "linux - " in the title.

If the question was about the way Bash executes it (check constraint before or after), I would have understand it. But asking the differences between those two with those explicit questions was for me an issue.

From my souvenir, I failed this because I tried to edit it.

What am I expecting from meta post?

- A review ban lift? No, I'm not ban!
- See if this Question fit on Stack Overflow? No, it's fit.

I want to discuss about the fact this question is a review trap and should be exclude of the review test.
No, it's not, edit to the question to make it better, or yes it's a good trap is the expected answers.

Comment: Did you read the comment you received on your self-deleted meta-question when you asked about this same review 6 weeks ago?

Comment: Should i delet this one edit the other and reopen it? the old one was just before getting in the car so i had no time taking care of it so i delete it while driving to ot get disturb by the notification.

Comment: No point doing so now... *updating the post in 40 min....* has made me chuckle though :)

Comment: "20 people thought it was good enough to upvote" So what .. I can dig close question with more upvote, and SCITE with double score! It does not make the review question a goof fit for a review trap.

Comment: I was more referring to the elements about what exactly the input/feedback was that you wanted from the community in asking the question.

Comment: I guess that question could (or should) be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: IMHO the audit is a bad one.  It has a down vote on it now so it will not be considered for an audit again.  Interestingly, after the OP made some edits to the post no one else(3 people) failed this as a audit.  Makes me wonder if edit(at least on a "know good question") should not fail an audit as even good post might need some editing.

Comment: Did they fail this test trying to edit or comment it, before the edit?

Comment: The audits were all after it was edited.  Looks like they all picked no action needed

Comment: I definitely don't think "edit" should fail this audit, just look at that last line of the question: A question mark followed by a hyphen followed by a lowercase word. There's at least *one* thing I'd want to change about that...Probably remove the hyphen, capitalize the next letter, and change the "unlikely" to a whole sentence (e.g. "I think that's unlikely").

Comment: What does "from my souvenir" mean?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, sorry in french souvenir is use for both memory and souvenir(the things you bring back from vacation like a memento, a keepsake). I used it here for memory. "From what I could recall" or "As I remember it" should be the right way to say this.